# Unreal add explosion effect on DestroyActor

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am a complete beginner, and as such I'm looking at some really basic tutorials like [this one](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/GettingStarted/HowTo/DetailsPanel/Collision/index.html)

At the end of it I thought "lets try and add an explosion effect when the third person character dies"

I looked into some function names and found that I have to use "Spawn Emitter at Location"
Fine! Turns out I need a Location as well , tried to drag it from the "As third Person Character" and found a nice "GetActorLocation".

Sweet and Simple, I'm understanding it !

WRONG, it doesn't work.

I even tried to add an "IsValid" node to check if the emitter is spawned, and it seems it is NOT.

I tried various fancy and creative ways to connect things..very beginner-like, but apparently I'm missing something.
Couldn't even find the same question anywhere, as the posts I saw were too difficult for my level.

As a side note, I already posted [this question](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/728954/modify-tutorial-with-explosion-on-destroyactormodi.html) on the unreal answer hub but received no answer since 2/3 days.

I hope someone can help me or at least point me in the right direction. Thanks

[image: blueprint]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are learning that's good but try to understand visual scripting does not change the rules of programming , you are destroying the actor(which is an object) and then spawning the emitter which will never fire . In normal programming languages if you delete/destroy an object can you use its functionality ? NO .

Now the matter at hand, spawn the emitter first and then after a delay node destroy your actor which will work as intended or if you want the actor to completely disappear and then emit a particle then first hide the actor mesh , spawn the emitter and after some delay destroy it. Hope it helps . Keep practicing. :)

Comment: Aren't the Actor I'm killing and the emitter I'm spawning two different objects? Or perhaps you mean that i can't retrieve the actor's location because it gets killed ?
On the other side, i tried just spawning the emitter after the actor is hit, i get "Valid" but it doesn't show at all (even manually adjusting the location of the emitter with that of the actor)

Comment: Is this code running on the actor your are destroying ?? If yes then no the particle wont spawn(yes they are two different objects), if no then try emitting the particle at 0,0,0 then check while the game is playing press shift + f1 and click on eject in the editor and find the emitter in the world out liner , see if its showing properly. BTW!!!!! in your picture you have not selected any emitter in the spawn emitter node !!!!!!!!!

Comment: Ah yes that was just a bad screenshot due to many tries.
Anyway, it seems i found the problem: i was simulating and not playing the selected viewport. its super strange for me, but it seems that if i simulate or even play the viewport but eject from the actor, no particles are seen (explosion). while if i stay inside the actor, i see the explosion.
Also, i don't understand what "code running on the actor" means, sorry for being too noob

Comment: also, pressing just f1 while playing (by mistake of course) showed me the polygon view and i was able to locate the emitter. which was not showing in the world outliner :/